# Why is $U$ $T$-invariant?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, invariance

Let $V$ a finite dimensional vector space and two sub-spaces, $U, W$ such that $V = U \oplus W$. Let's assume $T$ is a linear operator such that $W$ is $T$-invariant.

Why is it true that $U$ is also $T$-invariant?

Comment: It isn't in general. Is $V$ an inner product space, $W = U^\perp$ and $T$ normal?

Comment: It's not true for any linear map $T$.

Comment: For what it's worth: $W = \ker (T-2I)$ for some linear operator.

Answer (score 1):

Not true. For instance, let $V=\mathbb C^2$, and
$$
U=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}a\\0\end{bmatrix}:\ a\in\mathbb C\right\},\ \ 
W=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}0\\b\end{bmatrix}:\ b\in\mathbb C\right\}.
$$
Put 
$$
T=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $TW=W$, while $TU\not\subset U$.